# What would prevent a trigger from seeing rows in another table?

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2000

I have an `AFTER INSERT` trigger on this table, call it table 1.

And in the trigger I'm doing an update on another table, call it table 2.

I'm basically updating a field in table 2 from some related tables to table 1.

But for some reason the trigger can't see the row in the other table.

They are both in the same schema dbo.

What reasons would prevent the trigger from seeing the rows in the other table?

The update statement has a from clause.
But I tried just an exists clause in the trigger and it doesn't see it.

I did a sanity test with just the essentials and it worked fine.
But in the full solution it doesn't see the other table.

Comment: How do you obtain the `$id1` to pass to this script? Before it starts, you can't really know the new ID, can you? Also, do you get any errors as the result of the failure? I'm sure `desc` must be delimited for you to be able to use it as a name, because it's a reserved word.

Comment: I did a sanity test and broke it down to its essential parts.  And it worked as I expected.  Table 1 was updated just fine.  So I have to figure out why the trigger wouldn't be able to see table 1 in the real example.  I'll edit the question appropriately.